# How do i use "playVideoById()" through a Chrome Extension content script?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, youtube

Im building a chrome extension that will change videos after certain events but i noticed that the original youtube script does not change the URL but use some other (more effective) function. How do i change a youtube video without directly changing the URL?

This is for a Chrome Extension content script. I've tried the HTML5 video API but i dont think you can change the video through that.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "change the video". Video editing or just  loading another video on a page?

Comment: Loading another video, preferably the same way youtube itself does it

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Do i fetch the next video and inject it into the DOM?

Comment: You guessed right.

Comment: Ok, i have one more question, is this how youtube does it when you navigate through the website?

Comment: AJAX request is the only way to dynamically add a new content.

Comment: Ok, i checked out some other solutions for different contexts and they were recommending the Youtube Iframe API function player.playVideoById(), do you have any information on how i could use this in a content script on the youtube website?

Comment: I'm not closely familiar with Youtube API, but guess it uses AJAX/fetch requests under the hood. So most likely you don't need to use fetch API with Youtube API.

Comment: See [How to detect page navigation on Youtube and modify HTML before page is rendered?](//stackoverflow.com/a/34100952) and to access the page functions see [Insert code into the page context using a content script](//stackoverflow.com/q/9515704)